# How a SherlockFragment (container) accessing component inside Fragment?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have one SherlockFragmentActivity that act as container holding two fragments.

This is the main code of **SherlockFragmentActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat2);

        ActionBar objAction = getSupportActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        objAction.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        objAction.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // added for sherlock action bar plugin
        objAction.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ChatTab = objAction.newTab();
        ChatTab.setText("Chatting");
        ChatTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());

        TransferTab = objAction.newTab();
        TransferTab.setText("Transferred Items");
        TransferTab.setTabListener(new TabListener());

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        objAction.addTab(ChatTab);
        objAction.addTab(TransferTab);
}
```

but my question is how to Access for each component inside fragment by the main Activity? Let say, I want to access the button of the fragment. Where did i put this below code anyway? (sorry for asking)

```
btn_sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chatSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
btn_sendMessage = (Button) [object of your fragment].getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_chatSend);
```

P.S.: before using this please aware of Fragment Life Cycle otherwise you might get nullPointerException.